# What's wrong with my transport infrastructure? Things aren't moving!

Tags: tropico-5

I have a well-populated island: 1800 people, 41 raw resource buildings, 14 various factories, 12 docks, and 15 Teamsters' Offices. Traffic is fairly good – aside from the tourists' quarter, where it's fairly bad, but the tourists are off to the side. Plus, I have 17 Metro Stations to keep most cars off of the streets.

My problem is in getting goods transported around: half of my factories are missing one input good or another, and a quarter of my farms refuse to produce anything because they're full. When I added a couple of docks, this improved somewhat, but only for a short time – I'm getting full farms again. I've set both the Docks and Teamsters' Offices to maximum budget.

Is there a rule of thumb to find out whether I have enough Docks and Teamsters' Offices? How can I tell if I need to build one or the other, or both?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want 1 Teamsters Office for every 100 people according to the devs - There are a few isolated issues with teamsters getting stuck in certain buildings though. So i'd maybe bulldoze a few here and there and see if that doesn't fix the issue.

It also depends on how you structure your economy. If you're doing raw resources, you need less. You need more if you're focusing on production.

I would personally keep building till everything gets fixed.